# Why is it recommended not to allow querying the contract level for C++20 Contracts?

Tags: c++, c++20

The current C++ draft contains, in [[dcl.attr.contract.check](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.contract#check-3)] p3:

> There should be no programmatic way of setting, modifying, or querying
>   the build level of a translation unit.

I don't understand why it is recommended to not allow querying the contract level. With the current `assert` macro it is possible to detect if the assert is used via the `NDEBUG` macro.

Querying the contract level is useful in some cases like:

- adding additional variables to track additional state.
- transforming atomic store in atomic compare exchange to read the value.

what is the rationale behind recommending that querying the build level not be possible?

Comment: It would probably be a bad idea to query the contract level. If you do that your code would be contract-level dependent so that you would not be able to test your code by increasing the contract level. For the same reason side effects in contract violation checking causes UB.

Comment: To be honest this part of contracts seems to be less surprisingly confusing. @Oliv But it is a common practice to inspect and report current build settings (like "Debug, 32-bit, Checked").

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if that's the rationale but: contracts are not just a way to validate code. They also inject assumptions in the code. In other words: contract failures are UB even when runtime validation is not performed. Having the contracts, or the code around them, change based on build level would make that a mess.

Comment: @Oliv i agree that it should be used rarely, but sometimes it is needed to have good assets

Comment: @Frank Actualy I'am not sure at all. I should have written "UB caused by side effects in contract violation checking ensures this same independence"...

Comment: @Oliv I don't think we are talking about the same thing. I'm talking about valid (without side effects) contracts creating UB conditions even when the build level is at `off`, which leads to the importance of having the program be build-level invariant (within the as-if rule, of course).

Comment: @Tyker: "*adding additional variables to track additional state*" You can't do that, if those variables are used in a contract. Even if a contract isn't checked, the expression itself is [potentially evaluated](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def.odr#2). Meaning it has to be a legitimate expression, even if it isn't evaluated. Just like you can't do `decltype(variableThatDoesntExist)`.

Comment: @NicolBolas you can put the assert in a #ifndef

Comment: @Tyker: You assume that such a test would be a `#define` rather than a `constexpr` variable or function.

Comment: @NicolBolas wouldn't a #ifndef work for both ?

Comment: @Tyker: "Work for both" of what? You're asking why they don't give you a test, and as justification, you cited a use which is only viable (for the most part) if that test is a `#define`. You didn't specify the nature of the test in your question, only asking why there isn't one.

Comment: @NicolBolas i understood your comment wrong, yes the test would need to be #define based.

Comment: @Frank Indeed, we did not speak about the same thing. I was talking about [\[dcl.attr.contract\]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.contract#syn-6). You were talking about contract violation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is recommended that implementations not provide such a query because it would break mixed check-level usage.

As it currently stands, there is nothing formally wrong with building a library under one check-level, and linking it to code built under another. However, if code could easily query which check-level is available, that would potentially break this use case. Such a query can be used to affect the ABI of types and so forth. If the library has such an interface, then you have to build the consuming code under the same check-level, so that any headers and such would define the same ABI.

Is it possible to use such a query in a way that doesn't affect ABI and interfaces? Sure. But providing a test makes it *way too easy* to bungle.

As it currently stands, you can have a library have its own test, a `#define` which is expected to be defined when compiling under a particular checking level or somesuch. But such a define now is a part of your library's building interface. That's just part of your build documentation; if people build your library under check-level X, they must provide a `#define`. And any code consuming a library built under such circumstances must also provide that define.

And that's best part: the consuming code does not have to *share your check-level*. They have to share your *define*, but not the actual check-level. Your define belongs to the library; the check-level belongs to the user.

Comment: This does seem like a good reason to not allow querying the contract level, but do you have a source for the implied claim that this is *the* reason?